# br automático em versão mobile

Tags: html, css

Olá, estou com uma duvida, eu tenho uma pagina que fica num provedor que quando o usuário esgota a internet ela é apresentada! Mas eu queria que as imagens e os botões de compra de novos pacotes na versão mobile fossem colocados na vertical e não na horizontal! E queria deixar como esta na versão de desktop(na horizontal)! Alguém me pode dar um norte? Obrigado!

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
div#barra{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
div#barra h1{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 color: #fff;
}
div#text-a{
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ebebeb, #ccc);
}
div#text-a p{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
}
div#text-a a{
 color: #000;
}
div#barra-pacs{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
div#barra-pacs h1{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 23px;
 color: #fff;
}
.btn{
 color: #000;
}
.b{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
 <title>Comprar NET</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loja.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="barra">
<h1>IMM | Comprar NET</h1>
</div>
<div id="area">
<div id="text-a">
<p>Verificamos que atingiste o teu limite de dados, se quiseres continuar a navegar gratuitamente mas a uma velocidade de 127kb/s, <a onClick="freenet()" href="javascript:void();">Clica aqui!</a> Caso queiras continuar a navegar sem limites de velocidade compra um pacote abaixo!</p>
</div>
<div id="barra-pacs">
<h1>Pacotes</h1>
</div>
<div id="tabela">
<center>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/eCrWXz/5gb.jpg" title="5GB" alt="5GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/kWZwze/30gb.jpg" title="30GB" alt="30GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/essS5K/50gb.jpg" title="50GB" alt="50GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
 </tr>

</table>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nossa, em portugal a internet Banda Larga possui limite de dados ou isso é internet móvel?

Comment: Não possui é ilimitado, isto é de internet movel (Modem USB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc precisa criar uma regra `@media` para controlar como se comporta cada coisa no mobile e no desktop.

O modelo que eu fiz é bem básico, e como vc usou tabela e não um *grid* com divs por exemplo a solução que encontrei foi criando duas tabelas, uma pra mobile classe `.mobi` e outra pada desktop classe `.desk`

Depois eu fiz uma regra `@media` para só mostrar a tabela `.mobi` quando a tela for pequena. Exiba o exemplo abaixo como "Página toda" para ver que na tela maior a tabela `.desk` aparece a a `.mobi` some.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
div#barra{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
div#barra h1{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 color: #fff;
}
div#text-a{
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ebebeb, #ccc);
}
div#text-a p{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
}
div#text-a a{
 color: #000;
}
div#barra-pacs{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
div#barra-pacs h1{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 23px;
 color: #fff;
}
.btn{
 color: #000;
}
.b{
 display: none;
}
.mobi {
 display: none;
}
/* regras para mobile abaixo de 922px entra a tabela mobile e some a desk*/
@media screen and (max-width: 922px) {
    .mobi {
  display: table;
 }
    .desk {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div id="barra">
<h1>IMM | Comprar NET</h1>
</div>
<div id="area">
<div id="text-a">
<p>Verificamos que atingiste o teu limite de dados, se quiseres continuar a navegar gratuitamente mas a uma velocidade de 127kb/s, <a onClick="freenet()" href="javascript:void();">Clica aqui!</a> Caso queiras continuar a navegar sem limites de velocidade compra um pacote abaixo!</p>
</div>
<div id="barra-pacs">
<h1>Pacotes</h1>
</div>
<div id="tabela">
<center>
<table class="desk">
 <tr>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/eCrWXz/5gb.jpg" title="5GB" alt="5GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/kWZwze/30gb.jpg" title="30GB" alt="30GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/essS5K/50gb.jpg" title="50GB" alt="50GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
 </tr>

</table>
</center>
<center>
<table class="mobi">
 <tr>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/eCrWXz/5gb.jpg" title="5GB" alt="5GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/kWZwze/30gb.jpg" title="30GB" alt="30GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/essS5K/50gb.jpg" title="50GB" alt="50GB" width="300" height="460" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><center><a class="btn" href="#">Comprar</a></center></td>
 </tr>

</table>
</center>

</div>
</div>
```

***OBS 1*: Inclua também a meta tag `"viewport"` dentro do `<head>` do seu documento para dar certo!**

**OBS 2:** `<br>` não é para isso, e como vc usou table tr td o br não vai funcionar pois ele não quebra a estrutura tr td da table